# How to remove Linux from my Mac?

Tags: mac, unix

I have installed Ubuntu on my Mac. But then after a few times, neither can I boot to Ubuntu nor can I find where it actually is. Total a mystery. Now I actually try to erase this part in my computer. But I don't know where to start. Even in *Disk Utility* I do not see the space it takes. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Utility disk]

Please advise me how to erase Ubuntu and release the space. My internal SSD has a total size of 251 GB. But now I can only see 165 GB of it.

Thank PSN for his advice.But something weird just happened again.. This is what happened in my terminal when I tried to install the rEFInd:

dhcp-10-176-3-41:~ anthony$ /Users/anthony/Downloads/refind-bin-0.10.0/refind-install 
Not running as root; attempting to elevate privileges via sudo....
ShimSource is none
Installing rEFInd on OS X....
Installing rEFInd to the partition mounted at /Volumes/ESP
Found rEFInd installation in /Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind; upgrading it.

**** ALERT: SIP ENABLED! ****

You are attempting to upgrade an existing installation, but it appears that
System Integrity Protection (SIP) is enabled. If rEFInd is working now, then
this is fine; you can upgrade your existing rEFInd. If rEFInd is not working,
though, re-installing from this boot will not help. To re-enable rEFInd, you
must re-install it from a Recovery system or from another OS. To enter the
Recovery system and re-install rEFInd:

1. Reboot
2. Hold down Command+R as the chime sounds
3. When the OS has booted, select Utilities->Terminal
4. Change to this directory with the 'cd' command; it will probably be under
    /Volumes/Macintosch/Users/anthony
5. Re-run this script.

For more on this subject, see http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html

Do you want to attempt installation (Y/N)? y
Copied rEFInd binary files

Notice: Backed up existing icons directory as icons-backup.
Existing refind.conf file found; copying sample file as refind.conf-sample
to avoid overwriting your customizations.

Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc

WARNING: If you have an Advanced Format disk, *DO NOT* attempt to check the
bless status with 'bless --info', since this is known to cause disk corruption
on some systems!!

ALERT:
Installation has completed, but problems were detected. Review the output for
error messages and take corrective measures as necessary. You may need to
re-run this script or install manually before rEFInd will work.

Unmounting install dir
Volume EFI on disk0s1 unmounted

Answer (score 1):

I think the easier solution for you is :

• Do a back of your Macintosh partition : (Use Time Machine is probably a good idea)

• Restart you're computer with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> (Recovery mode)
 (You may need to be connected to internet with an ethernet connexion)

• From there Do a clean install within your time machine.

[image]

And there you should be done !

Answer (score 0):

To use the Ubuntu installed in your Mac you have to install rEFInd which is used to manage boot loaders on a Mac(The rEFInd will auto-detect the installed boot loaders .

**How to use rEFInd**

- Download rEFInd from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/)*
- Open a Terminal window by pressing Command + Space and, typing Terminal, and pressing Enter.
- Drag and drop the install.sh file from the downloaded zip file into the terminal window and press Enter to run it.
- Shut down your Mac -a full shut down, not a restart — and boot it back up again. You should see the rEFInd boot manager screen.(If not Press and Hold Alt button and when it boots up select EFI Disk Icon(If Exist)).

*Now for your next Question on how to uninstall Ubuntu from Mac the best solution I suggest is:*

- Get an Ubuntu – Live CD. You will need it to delete the Linux
  partitions Boot into the Ubuntu Live CD (press the C button while
  restarting with the Ubuntu CD/DVD in the drive)
- Start Gparted the
  Ubuntu partitioning program. If unsure on how to do this, just go the
  the ‘Dash Home’ and search for Gparted Delete the Linux partition Set
  the swap partition to “off”.
- Do NOT re-size the Mac-OS partition while in
  Gparted this will be done from Mac-OS Reboot the laptop and boot into
  Mac OS X Start the Disk Utility application and go to ‘Partition’
- Re-size the Mac OS partition by dragging it to the bottom to take up
  the space that had been taken up by Ubuntu Re-boot and make sure
  those changes have taken effect Next we need to delete rEFInd
- Instructions for
  uninstalling rEFInd are located at their site here In my case method
  1 was the one applicable Delete the efi folder Delete rEFInd
  folder in “Library/StartupItems” Reboot and that’s it!!

***Edit:***

```
error "Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc"
```

*If you get some errors like mentioned above it is because System Integrity Protection is enabled on your Mac.You can disable it by following the steps below.*

**How to Disable SIP**

- Restart the computer, while booting hold down Command-R to boot into
  recovery mode.
- Once booted, navigate to the “Utilities > Terminal” in the top menu
  bar.
- Enter csrutil disable in the terminal window and hit the return key.
- Restart the machine and System Integrity Protection will now be
  disabled.

Credits: [HarlemSquirrel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/149628/harlemsquirrel)

Comment: Thank you for your advise.. But bugs happened again. Please check my post , I edited it again. Thank you!

Comment: Ok.This is due to SIP enabled on your Mac.I have edited my answer please check that.Hope this helps.